# Android Replace Action Bar with Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I'm new to Android and would like to replace ActionBar with Tabs like in facebook Messager app or AirBnB app.

I have tried to find tutorials but could not find any.

Can anyone suggest resources or tutorials that could help me achieve that kind of actionbar?
Thx!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just hide action bar for that `TabActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

hide the actionbar and use toolbar (any layout ) to make your custom layout like facebook.